# Overload function return type with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-query

I am trying to build a generic "req" function that takes an URL path (string), and object (GET/POST params) as arguments, and returns the results with the appropriate type inferred.

This would be the interface from where my functions gets its type defs:

```
interface ValidQueries{
    books: (q: {
        limit?: number;
        category?: string;
    }) => Book[];

    authors: (q: {
        name?: string;
    }) => Author[];
}
```

And an attempt to write the function:

```
const req = <K extends keyof ValidQueries>(path: string, params: (Parameters<ValidQueries[K]>[0])) => {
    return useQuery([path, params], ({ queryKey }) => {
        const [, params] = queryKey;
        return httpRequest(path, params) as Promise<ReturnType<ValidQueries[K]>>;
    });
};
```

Example:

`req("books", { limit: 10 });` -> return type should appear as Book[], and 2nd arg should appear as type of "q" from the matching function in the interface.

the `params` type definition does not appear to be correct. I wanted to take the type of the first param from the functions in my interface (q).

And the return type `Promise<ValidQueries[K]>` sort of works, but its not ideal because I see all possible types, like `Book[] | Author[]`, instead of just `Book[]` if I pass "books" as first arg, or just `Author[]` if I pass "authors" as the first arg...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most importantly, when you use generics you need to have some anchor, that TypeScript may [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) from. In this function, you use `path: string` (so any string), and the only argument using generic `K` is `params`.

Because of that, when you call `req("books", { limit: 10 })`, to compute the generic `K` it will do something like `Extract<ValidQueries[keyof ValidQueries], { limit: 10 }>`. To fix that, you may use `K` for the path argument - `path: K`. That will help to find the proper method from `ValidQueries`.

It should also solve the problem with `Book[] | Author[]`, unless the `useQuery` has incorrect types (then you may push your `as …` clause to the end, or type the function return type directly).

Additionally, you may use [rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters) like `...params: Parameters<…>`, so it will allow passing any number of `ValidQueries[K]` arguments down. It will also add the `q:` name to the parameter in the IDE, that you expected.

Summing up, you have something like this:

```
interface ValidQueries {
  books: (q: { limit?: number, category?: string }) => Book[];
  authors: (q: { name?: string }) => Author[];
}

const req = <K extends keyof ValidQueries, T extends ValidQueries[K]>(path: K, ...params: Parameters<T>) => {
  return useQuery([ path, params ], ({ queryKey }) => {
    const [ , params ] = queryKey;
    return httpRequest(path, params) as Promise<ReturnType<T>>;
  });
};
```

It has a small adjustment though, that the `T` type is created here automatically, as an alias. You could use the full `Parameters<ValidQueries[K]>` form (and similarly for the return type).